# Cannot compile with buildroot 2022.08.1

Tags: javascript, c++, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm having issues compiling with buildroot 2022.08.1. There seems to be nothing on the internet (that I can find anyway) that can help me so I'm turning to the legends of the internet.

Currently on linux mint 20.3, Kernel 5.19-surface

Normally I wouldn't ask but I can't really find much of a specific error message here that I can understand. I have compiled with buildroot on this computer before with just the default defconfig for the raspberry pi 3 but obviously having more configuration on that profile has opened it up to issues.

The build nearly finishes and then does the following:

```
[ 26%] Building CXX object Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore.dir/__/__/JavaScriptCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-f0a787a9-7.cpp.o
aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-g++.br_real: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore.dir/build.make:1175: Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore.dir/__/__/JavaScriptCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-23a5fd0e-6.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** Deleting file 'Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore.dir/__/__/JavaScriptCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-23a5fd0e-6.cpp.o'
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from assembler/MacroAssembler.h:46,
                 from jit/Reg.h:30,
                 from jit/RegisterAtOffset.h:30,
                 from jit/RegisterAtOffsetList.h:30,
                 from jit/JITCode.h:33,
                 from runtime/ExecutableBase.h:32,
                 from runtime/ScriptExecutable.h:28,
                 from runtime/FunctionExecutable.h:30,
                 from runtime/JSFunctionInlines.h:28,
                 from ./bytecode/AccessCase.h:33,
                 from ./bytecode/AccessCase.cpp:27,
                 from ../../JavaScriptCore/DerivedSources/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-f0a787a9-1.cpp:1:
assembler/MacroAssemblerARM64.h: In member function ‘JSC::ARM64Assembler::ExtendType JSC::MacroAssemblerARM64::indexExtendType(JSC::AbstractMacroAssembler<JSC::ARM64Assembler>::BaseIndex)’:
assembler/MacroAssemblerARM64.h:1523:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 1523 |     }
      |     ^
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:769: Source/JavaScriptCore/CMakeFiles/JavaScriptCore.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:293: /home/aussietanz/buildroot-2022.08.1/output/build/webkitgtk-2.36.7/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

Thought it may have been something to do with not enough storage allocated for the .img file (originally 300M because it's a very bare bones raspi3 image with only bash, graphics utilities and python), but i've added a bit more(an extra 200M) and it still has the same issue.

Help appreciated.

Comment: "*I can't really find much of a specific error message here ...*" -- The error message indicates an issue with reading/parsing the JavaScriptCore source code, specifically the file **assembler/MacroAssemblerARM64.h** at line 1523. Try manually inspecting that file for corruption.

Comment: *"... That I understand."* - Thanks for pointing out the error. I wouldn't have even noticed to be honest. How do I even go about inspecting it? What do I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-g++.br_real: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
```

This is a typical symptom of an OOM (Out-Of-Memory) - the v8 javascript engine takes a lot of memory. Check the kernel logs on your build machine (`journalctl -ke` or `dmesg | less`) just after this error happens.

If it is indeed an OOM, it is sometimes possible to work around it by reducing parallelism. You can do this by setting `BR2_JLEVEL` to a lower value in the Buildroot configuration.

Comment: I haven't found much about setting this value in config files, but it appears if I append the "-j" to the "make" command with the desired value (in this case, 1), it should override the BR2_JLEVEL, no?

Comment: If you're talking about the outer `make` command that you type to launch buildroot - no, buildroot overrides the `-j` given on the commandline. You can simply set JLEVEL in menuconfig (menu "Build options", the 5th option "Number of jobs to run simultaneously").

Comment: Ah thanks so much dude - this was the solution. Just set it to 2 and it took 4 hours or so to compile. You're a lifesaver.